# JPA entities in dependency jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was wondering if we can create a utility jar which has its own JPA entities and accesses the database and we can include this jar in other java projects?

Comment: Yes, you can. Put the JPA entity classes in a library and include that as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, i am using this method.

Have to add each module its own `persistence.xml` with its own `<persistence-unit>`, thou.